# PermanentTaskFailure with deferred API in appengine standard python (issues started in summer/Fall 2019)

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine-python

I recently have started seeing issues with the deferred API. No change on my app that has been running for years.

If I read what is happening correctly is that the deferred API stores its payload in the datastore. Then when the task runs, it tries to retrieve but does not find it and raises PermanentTaskFailure

Anybody, has run into the same issue, any clues what has changed in appengine recently?

The pattern is:

1. Web request comes in
2. web requests starts a deferred task with a an array of N items
3. task executes and performs work for 1 item then repeats step 2 for the remaining N-1 items (until there are no items)

failure happens after the 2nd or 3rd item

some pointers and logs:
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5qPoS.png) https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/refdocs/modules/google/appengine/ext/deferred/deferred
[image]

Comment: In the log you shared it mentions that the error was while calling run_from_datastore, can you share what you do in that function?

Comment: Is it possible that your array size got larger? In the source code you pointed to it appears that `run_from_datastore` is only invoked on the `except taskqueue.TaskTooLargeError:` path. If so you could try splitting it in multiple deferred tasks right from the beginning. Maybe even 1 item per task? - you're only processing one item at each iteration anyways.